# One long character to multiple columns

Tags: r, regex

I have this dataframe

```
df1 <- data.frame(Note = c("Profit before tax 240 tSEK",
                           "Earnings per share 0.240 " ,
                           "Ali de Margin 37 %"),
                  Line = c(6, 2, 2))
```

I want something like below

```
Note                 Val    Unit    Line
Profit before tax    240    tSEK    6
Earnings per share   0.240          2
Ali de Margin        37      %      2
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Write an appropriate regex. See `help("regmatches")` and `help("regex")` as well as numerous regex tutorials.

Comment: So, `Val` is the last(/only?) numeric field, and `Unit` is the optional string after it?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) function `tstrsplit`, splitting your variable `Note` on the space either prior to digits or after a number with digits (with or without dot), using regex and lookarounds:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, c("Note", "Val", "Unit"):=tstrsplit(Note, "( (?=[0-9.]+))|((?<=\\d) )", perl=TRUE)]
df1
#                 Note Line   Val Unit
#1:  Profit before tax    6   240 tSEK
#2: Earnings per share    2 0.240   NA
#3:      Ali de Margin    2    37    %
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also play with `regexpr` & `regmatches` functions:

```
pattern <- regexpr("[[:digit:]]+\\.*[[:digit:]]+", df$note)
note <- substr(df$note, 1, pattern-2)
value <- regmatches(df$note, pattern)
unit <- substr(df$note, 
              pattern+attr(pattern, "match.length")+1,
              nchar(as.character(df$note)))

result <- data.frame(note=note, value=value, unit=unit, line=df$Lines)

#                note value unit line
#1  Profit before tax   240 tSEK    6
#2 Earnings per share 0.240         2
#3      Ali de Margin    37    %    2
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use `tidyr::extract`. The `extract` function provides flexibility to define `regex` to capture groups and separate column in multiple columns.

```
library(tidyr)

extract(df1, Note, into = c("Note", "Val", "Unit"),
                regex = "^([[:alpha:][:blank:]]+)\\s([[:digit:].]+)(.*)")

#                 Note   Val  Unit Line
# 1  Profit before tax   240  tSEK    6
# 2 Earnings per share 0.240          2
# 3      Ali de Margin    37     %    2
```

> ```
> **Regex explanation:**
>
> ^([[:alpha:][:blank:]]+)  -- Group 1 => Any number of character/spaces 
> \\s                       -- Leave a space between Group 1 and Group 2
> ([[:digit:].]+)           -- Group 2 => Any number of digits/.
> (.*)                      -- Gropu 3 => Any thing after 2nd group till end.
> ```